# Run app with higher SDK on lower SDK

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I wanted to know whether an app developed in Android 3.0 runs on Android 2.1. If so, how can I do that?

If I develop the app using the libraries from 3.0 such as fragments, will it work in 2.1?

Comment: How do add backward compatibility to my project?

Comment: actually fragments are not available in 2.1 so as told by @Lukas Knuth always try to focus the possible lowest android version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to write an app targeted for 3.0 that also runs under 2.1. However, it requires careful use of libraries and the Compatibility library.

The first step is to set appropriate `android:minSdkVersion` and `android:targetSdkVersion` values in your manifest file. This will define which range of devices will allow your app to run.

The second is to ensure you do not use any API functions from later SDKs on platforms with lower versions - attempts (such as trying to use ActionBar on a 2.2 device) will cause your app to crash.

I'd strongly recommend reading Reto Meier's articles on maintaining backwards compatibility:
http://blog.radioactiveyak.com/2011/01/how-to-use-gyroscope-api-and-remain.html
http://blog.radioactiveyak.com/2011/02/strategies-for-honeycomb-and-backwards.html

In addition, the source for [Googles I/O app](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/) is definitely worth examining to see how they handle running on a wide range of devices, whilst still utilising features of Honeycomb (and later) releases.

Answer (score 2):

No. But a 2.1 App will run under 3.0

You can try to copy your code and use it with the 2.1 library, but some things won't work (you'll need to do some extra work to port it back).

Comment: I have downloaded google iosched project which is targeted for api level 11. I t runs perfectly on android 2.2(api level 8).

Comment: Well, if it works: fine. If not: You know where to look for it. Always try to target the lowest Android Version possible (Should be 2.2 or 2.1 by now).