# how to support app to run on all devices that contain finger print feature

Tags: java, android, android-studio, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

hi sir hope you are right. I am working on app that contain fingerprint feature in it at one point and which fingerprint sdk i enabled its min minSdkVersion is  23 and i want to allow this app to run on all devices when i changed  minSdkVersion to 16 then its not running. here is the error mesage below which it shows

```
Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 23 declared in library [me.aflak.libraries:fingerprint:2.5.3] C:\Users\Zahid Iqbal\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\0f64be97807f594934240311bd0e96bb\jetified-fingerprint-2.5.3\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
    or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 23,
    or use tools:overrideLibrary="me.aflak.libraries" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

here is he manifest for the jetified-fingerprint

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="me.aflak.libraries"
android:versionCode="37"
android:versionName="2.5.3">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="23"
    android:targetSdkVersion="27" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a library with minimum Sdk version above your own minimum Sdk version. Omar Aflak (https://github.com/OmarAflak/Fingerprint) uses minSDK 23 in his library. You have to raise your minimum version or use another library.

I just read in this article https://jaxenter.de/fingerprint-sensor-in-android-das-muessen-entwickler-wissen-36481 (sorry, it's german) that fingerprint support was added in SDK 23 (Marshmallow Android). So you do not even need to support older versions.

Maybe this can help you further [Run app with higher SDK on lower SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109980/run-app-with-higher-sdk-on-lower-sdk)

Comment: sir i dont want to use it with lower version i just want that app runs on all devices if device has fingerprint then user can us if not then also app needs to run.

Comment: for that purpose i decrease the sdk version to 16 and got error i posted above

Comment: I added a link in my answer that might be helpful